Options to fill the information in the lookup column of the document library after migration from SP 2013 to SPO
In my SP 2013 site I have a calendar and a document library that has a lookup column, taking values from the Title column of the Calendar.
I am migrating my SP2013 site to SPO site.
We used ShareGate to migrate the content of the site, but the Calendar and document library have been migrated separately and lookup column in the library is empty. The number of files in the library is too big to manually enter the information in the lookup column. item
What are my options to fill in the lookup information in the document library?
We don't want to delete the document library and start the migration over, because the library item forms on the SPO have already been heavily customized with Power App and it would be lost if we delete the library and start migration over.

Let's see if the PowerShell command to update the lookup column value in this article will help you: SharePoint Online: PowerShell to List All Files in a Document Library
